# What does it mean to designate something as "prey" in the Bravo Feat?

Tags: dnd-4e, feats

From the online compendium:

> ### Bravo [Multiclass Bravo]
>
> **Benefit:** You gain training in the Intimidate skill. 
>   Once per encounter, as a minor action, you can designate one creature you can see as your prey, gaining +2 to attack rolls and damage rolls against that creature until the end of your next turn. The creature remains your prey until it drops to 0 hit points, until you end the effect as a free action, or until the end of the encounter—whichever comes first.

If the effect only lasts until the end of my next turn, why the distinction that it remains my prey?

Answer (score 6):

**Prey is an effect**

When you use the power granted you by the multiclass Bravo feat you are causing an effect to  give the creature in question the Prey keyword. This keyword is specific and useable only if you multiclass Bravo. The benefits applied as described by the multiclass Bravo feat happen, and while that creature is your Prey other feat based powers that are unlocked when you take multiclass Bravo rely on it.

Bravo Novice (4), Bravo Expert (8), and Bravo Specialist (10) all work off of or give you an additional benefit against the creature that is currently your Prey.

Answer (score 3):

I did find one thing that requires you to have marked something specifically as 'prey': Bravo's Finish. This feat utility can be found in the compendium but the key line is:

> **Target**: One creature that is your prey.

So, there are other feats that need this "prey" condition to be met specifically, in order for you to use them. This feat (and possibly others) is why the prey distinction is kept.

Comment: I wanted to share another thought I have, but since I have no info to back up my hypothesis I did not include it in my official answer. I get the feeling that marking something as "prey" also means you have "marked" the target and therefore it would get the -2 to attack rolls and all the other things that come with the "marked" condition.

Comment: I very much doubt that.  The original text in the question seems to go out of its way to avoid saying "mark" in the phrasing. (to be clear, I doubt your comment, I upvoted your answer)

Comment: @Ryno exactly why I put it as a comment and not in my full answer, it was just a hunch I had, and even after more research on that topic I couldn't find any corroboration of my suspicions. I am still on the fence about it and if it came up in the game I am DMing, I would likely bend the rules in favor of prey=marked. That said I fully agree that if they meant marked they probably would have just said "marked", I just tend to be an easy-going DM that usually house-rules in favor of the players. ;)

Comment: @MC_Hambone, No, Prey is not the same as marking. Marking is a very specific condition in 4e, and will always use the word "mark"/"marked" or similar, not "designate".